# Facebook app no longer requests the correct permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I built a facebook app that uses XMPP to connect to facebook chat. And it has worked great. But recently on accounts that I am trying to authorize it does not request the correct permissions, stopping my app from working. Bellow are two screenshots of the permissions my app is getting from facebook. One clearly shows more permission than the other. My code for requesting permission has not changed:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                        savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                        .setPermissions(
                                Arrays.asList("xmpp_login",
                                        "user_online_presence",
                                        "friends_online_presence",
                                        "read_mailbox", "read_friendlists"))
                        .setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }
```

Correct permissions:
[image]

Incorrect:

[image]

Comment: Do you get a dialog from your the facebook app with the requested permissions? Because If I remember correctly when you start your session it should request those permissions (if not in an authenticated session)

Comment: Those screenshots show what permissions that user *has* granted to the app, they don't show what permission set appears in auth dialog which appears to the user - is that correctly ask for the permissions you're requesting? If not, are you sure the session you try to open is having the requested permission set applied correctly?

Comment: @Igy After doing some testing it seems it is inconsistent when asking for permissions from users when they authenticate, even though my code never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab at what to address (reading through the docs) - but too long for coments.

The difference appears to be that the first user has previously authenticated the app: you can tell as "last access" is "Basic Information". In this case, the user might have "SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED" but the other user might have "SessionState.CREATED" as there was no previously cached token. What happens if you check for both states before calling "openForRead"? Do you have another "open" elsewhere that probably sweeps up if this one fails? That other one might not ask for permissions.

Another comment based on docs is that your call to "Session.setActiveSession(session);" you can't call this with a session that is not yet open. So you probably should move that to after the "openForRead" call otherwise it may throw exception and again, another open() request sweeps up the aftermath.

Comment: Thank you! You were completely right, i didn't realize it but when the `if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED))` statement wasn't satisfied it skipped over that login and used another login That I didn't realize was in there without the correct permissions. You were even right about the exceptions it kept throwing over and over. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Peter if this is the right answer give Robbie the bounty ;) cheers

Comment: @Dyna thanks for the reminder, I forgot the bounty is awarded separately from marking correct :)

Comment: Thanks.  You're not the only one to forget.  Another bounty question I just answered didn't even get acknowledged.  Not that points matter, it's just nice to know the answers help. Good luck with the application.